# How to send a push notification from the Firebase console to a specific GCM/FCM device token ID

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-console

In Urban Airship, when I am composing a notification, I can target specific users by searching for a Urban Airship `channel_id` (device ID):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I sent from Urban Airship the push notification that I am showing above, and I received it successfully. Now I want to do the same thing, send a push notification to a specific device, but now using the Firebase console. The problem is that in Firebase, in the step where I need to specify the `target`, it only allows me to choose `User segment` or `topic`. I was expecting to see a third option: `Target specific users` (for sending notifications to one or many specific GCM/FCM device token IDs. So my alternative is to add a GCM/FCM device token ID to a `topic` and then send the push notification to that topic, which is something that I have successfully done before. Nonetheless, that would be a workaround and not the way I would prefer to do this. Is it possible to send push notifications to specific users (by defining the target GCM/FCM device token IDs) from the Firebase console? Thank you.

**UPDATE 1:** See how the Firebase console (https://console.firebase.google.com/) only shows `User segment` and `Topic` as the `Target`:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By design, the notification feature in the console is for sending out broadcast-type events. Sending user-specific alerts would be more of a programmatic operation done through the API.

For sending test messages, there is a console tool for this, explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/first-message).

Note that it is possible to send a notification to one device by [subscribing a device to any topic](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/topic-messaging#subscribe_the_client_app_to_a_topic) and sending the notification to that topic in the console (keep in mind topics are public and you can't prevent users from signing up to them; fine for testing most likely).

Another alternative is to send a message via HTTP or curl. Perhaps the best resource for this is the [quickstart/messaging example](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/tree/master/messaging#getting-started).

Comment: Thank you. I completed successfully the migration from Urban Airship to Firebase and did some of the things you mentioned in your answer. I am very glad with Firebase and I do not have to pay for the Urban Airship membership anymore. I have been sending push notifications for free to thousands of devices with Firebase. Thank you Kato for your answer.

Answer (score 18):

**First Step: [image]**

**Second Step: [image]**

**Third Step: [image]**

Comment: By the way, it did not work. I saw and used the option you shared, but it did not work. The notification was never received. What I had to do was to add the GCM/FCM device token ID to a `topic` and then send the notification to the topic. That worked. No idea why that test feature that you showed in your answer did not send the push notification to my test phone, or why it was not received even though all other notifications were received correctly on that same device I used for testing purposes.

Comment: Bro first answer is correct and second is you are doing mistake in code so fcm console not work properly for you.

Comment: @BlackBind Thanks. You say it very confidently and do not seem to consider the possibility of the `Test` feature not working properly. I doubt the problem is in my code because when I add the same `GCM/FCM device token ID` to a `topic` and then push the notification to that `topic` from Firebase, I do receive the notification, demonstrating that the `GCM/FCM device token ID` is the right one that belongs to my device and that my implementation/code is correct.

Comment: first share your code . can you share your device id

Comment: The implementation of push notifications with Firebase is not one line of code to share it and fortunately it is already working for me. It just surprises me that the `Test` feature shared in this answer did not work for me but other than that, everything works correctly for my Firebase implementation, which I am glad about. Thank you BlackBlind :)

Comment: Ok bro if any problem in notification you can ask me again

Comment: Thank you very much BlackBlind. Your answer provided what I was looking for, even though for some reason that `Test` feature did not work for me but that is another topic. Thanks again.